# Eye problems with dragon

Tags: modeling, mesh

Okay I'm trying to create this model for a character of mine I call "Truth Dragon".

Only problem is, this sucker has two sets of eyes. One small and the other is bigger. Here's a sketch of what I mean.

[image: "Nom Nom"]

So I got most of it done and this is what I got so far, until I went to scupt/object mode.

[image: Pretty boi]
[image: WTF Is that!?]

For some reason, the second eye on the top is doing something weird. I've deleted all duplicates, messing with it in scuplt just messes up the eye shape. 
I definitely have no idea why the nose is doing that. 
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5637/ Here's the file if you need to see for yourself.

Comment: can you add your blend file to your question? Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Multires modifyer doesn't like to work with Ngons. So redo the eye openings without using any Ngons, only quads.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by Ngons and Quads? Sorry, I'm a beginner at this stuff

Comment: Quads are faces with 4 edges and Ngons are faces with more than 4 edges. ( tris are triangles ) .